Unable to get USB Serial path/connection on Ubuntu
What I did so far. Activating the relevant driver & disabling Braille support - which seems to be often the root of the trouble. Reboot.
sudo modprobe cp210x
sudo apt remove brltty

Confirming everything is in place:
sudo lsmod | grep cp210x
cp210x                 36864  0
usbserial              49152  1 cp210x

Plugging the device in. It is found:
dmesg 
[  130.776659] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbserial_generic
[  130.776672] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for generic
[  130.779299] usbcore: registered new interface driver cp210x
[  130.779324] usbserial: USB Serial support registered for cp210x
[  153.870560] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  169.708562] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  169.819779] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=18ef, idProduct=e026, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  169.819785] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  169.819788] usb 1-1.2: Product: EWD 100
[  169.819790] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[  169.819792] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: N0VNELCPLVW9SQVJ


lsusb 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 147e:2020 Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode)
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 18ef:e026  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c03e Logitech, Inc. Premium Optical Wheel Mouse (M-BT58)
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1ab1:0c94 Rigol Technologies 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lsusb -d 18ef:e026 -v

Bus 001 Device 005: ID 18ef:e026  
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x18ef 
  idProduct          0xe026 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Silicon Labs
  iProduct                2 EWD 100
  iSerial                 3 N0VNELCPLVW9SQVJ
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           32
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              100mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           2
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              2 EWD 100
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x01  EP 1 OUT
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               0
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)

However, nothing to be found at ls -al /dev | grep -i ttyUSB.
Any ideas what further to check? I would highly appreciate it!

you are right. sorry !

Note that the lsusb does not display any vendor/product information for the device. Since you know it should be an USB-Serial device, that probably means the device manufacturer has configured the USB-Serial converter chip with a custom vendor/product ID.
Searching for the ID values in the USB ID Repository indicates the vendor ID 18ef is associated with ELV Elektronik AG. Googling for "ELV Elektronik" and the iProduct string "EWD 100" mentioned in the lsusb -v listing for the device brought me here:
https://de.elv.com/p/elv-bausatz-elektronische-widerstandsdekade-ewd-100-P130476/?itemId=130476
Is this the device you're trying to get working?
Loading the Windows driver package and inspecting the slabvcp.inf file inside it confirms that the driver is indeed for a Silicon Laboratories CP210x serial converter. So you'll need to teach the Linux cp210x module a new vendor/device ID pair to recognize. Fortunately, there is a system for that.
To test if the theory is correct, first run sudo modprobe cp210x, and then this command:
echo "18ef e026" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id >/dev/null

This tells the cp210x serial converter module to assume any USB device with that vendor/product ID pair is actually a Silicon Laboratories CP210x serial converter. That should allow the module to recognize the device and present a /dev/ttyUSB* device for it. If you can see the device, keep on reading.
The modprobe command and the addition of the ID are non-persistent: you would have to re-enter these commands after each reboot.
To make this configuration persistent, you should create a file named /etc/modprobe.d/ewd-100.conf (you can name it anything you want, the filename just needs to have the .conf suffix), with the following contents:
alias usb:v18EFpE026d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in* cp210x
install cp210x /sbin/modprobe -i cp210x; /bin/echo '18ef e026' >>/sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/cp210x/new_id 

The first line tells the kernel module autoloading mechanism to load the cp210x module whenever a USB device with that vendor/product ID pair is detected; the second line automates the command to feed the new IDs to the module itself after it's loaded.
After adding these settings and rebooting (or running sudo depmod), the system should now auto-detect the device and present a /dev/ttyUSB* device for it as soon as you plug it in.

Perfect answer! Indeed the vendor/device ID wasn't recognize. Thank you!
